# Docusaurus 2 - How to add an button in right items to Navbar in mobile view?

Tags: docusaurus

I'd like to add an item like a button (Most likely GitHub link) in right items to Navbar in mobile view like below.

I didn't see any option in `docusaurus.config.js` for that.

```
navbar: {
        items: [
          { to: "/docs/get-started", label: "HOME", position: "left" },
          { to: "/docs/get-started", label: "GET STARTED", position: "left" },
          { to: "/docs/learn", label: "LEARN", position: "left" },
          { to: "/docs/api", label: "API", position: "left" },
          {
            href: "https://dev.to/nucleoid",
            label: "BLOG",
            position: "left",
          },
          {
            href: "https://github.com/NucleoidJS/Nucleoid",
            html: require("fs").readFileSync("./github.html", "utf8"),
            position: "right",
          },
        ],
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

since the right navbar items will set to `display: none` when the viewport is smaller then `996px`, you may override them with custom css as follow:

```css
@media (max-width: 996px) {
  div.navbar__items.navbar__items--right > * {
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
  }
}
```

mobile view setup are mentioned in the [docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/styling-layout#mobile-view)